# MONGODB : Retreive parent document in same collection than childs documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I got a little headache on a request mongoDb. I got a collection with documents which can have a parent document in the same collection. This is my collection.

PARENT DOCUMENT

```
{
    "_id": {"$oid": "5f9cac3598361b3370ea47c6"},
    "title": "My Title",
    "type":1,
    "question": "",
    "answerList": [],
    "__v": 0
}
```

CHILD 1

```
{
    "_id": {"$oid": "5f9cac3598361b3370ea47c7"},
    "title": "My Title",
    "type":1,
    "question": "Q1 ?",
    "answerList": [
    {
         "_id": {"$oid": "5f9cac3598361b3370ea47c9"},
        "answer": "Hello1",
    }, 
    {
        "_id": {"$oid": "5f9cac3598361b3370ea47c8"},
        "answer": "Hello2",
    }],
    "parentId": {"$oid": "5f9cac3598361b3370ea47c6"},
    "__v": 0
}
```

CHILD 2

```
{
    "_id": {"$oid": "5f9cac3598361b3370ea47ca"},
    "title": "My Title",
    "type":1,
    "question": "Q2",
    "answerList": [
     {
        "_id": {"$oid": "5f9cac3598361b3370ea47cc"},
        "answer": "Byebye1"
     }, 
     {
        "_id": {"$oid": "5f9cac3598361b3370ea47cb"},
        "answer": "Byebye2",
    }],
    "feedType": "SURVEY",
    "parentId": {"$oid": "5f9cac3598361b3370ea47c6"},
    "__v": 0
}
```

**EDIT**

I want to make a request by fields **question** and **answerList** and **type**. logically only the children documents are returned. The problem is: if some documents have a parent I want ONLY the parent document, if a document have no parent I want to return this document. I can't figure out how to do that help me please

My base request

```
var polls = MyModel.find({
  $and: [
    { confidentiality: ConfidentialityEnum.PUBLIC },
    {
      $or: [
        { question: { $regex: fields.query, $options: "i" } },
        {
          answerList: {
            $elemMatch: { answer: { $regex: fields.query, $options: "i" } },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
})
  .populate("createdBy", ["firstName", "lastName", "avatar"])
  .select("+voteList")
  .populate("voteList.user", ["_id", "avatar"])
  .select("+commentList")
  .populate("commentList.user", "_id")
  .then((data) => {
    return data;
  });
```

New request (thx @Brmm)

```
const result = MyModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        { confidentiality: ConfidentialityEnum.PUBLIC },
        {
          $or: [
            { question: { $regex: fields.query, $options: 'i' } },
            {
              answerList: {
                $elemMatch: { answer: { $regex: fields.query, $options: 'i' } },
              },
            },
          ],
        }
      ]
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'questions',
      localField: 'parentId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'parent',
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$parent',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
]).then((data => {
    console.log(data);
}))
```

Problems :

- In the console.log I get the documents which have parents instead of only the parent document.
- Is it possible to populate my result with MyModel.aggregate ?

Thank you in advance ! :)

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You should split up your data in a "question" and "answer" collection and use $lookup aggregation pipelines.

That being said, if you really want it like this you can try the following pipeline. Note that the $unwind makes sure you only have one parent per result. If you have multiple parents with the same id you will get multiple separate results. If you want an array of all parents then drop the $unwind.

```
const result = await MyModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { question: { $regex: 'Byebye', $options: 'i' } },
        {
          answerList: {
            $elemMatch: { answer: { $regex: 'Byebye', $options: 'i' } },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'questions',
      localField: 'parentId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'parent',
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$parent',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
])
```

Comment: @AltoDev Feel free to make a new question if you have other problems, If my answer helped you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: ur resquest only return the Childs element. i edit my post to show the code that i tested